# How reasonable to make ansible work on systems with restrictive umask?

Tags: permissions, umask, ansible

Q1. If you setup `root` with a restrictive umask, it will affect the files created when you run ansible, right?  (Unless you tell ansible to ensure a specific mode aka. permissions).

A1. Looks like it, ansible does not automatically reset the umask.

- [Using ansible to upgrade ansible in envronment with restrictive umask](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/aAuiOJpA2Co)
- [[ansible-project] Temporarily setting umask](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/1499yrsrz4/temporarily-setting-umask)

Q2. What can we conclude from this?

1. Is there a way to write ansible roles that they will never depend on the umask?
2. Are there disadvantages of writing an ansible role to work under this constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible now answers this question by adding a `umask` option, to modules like the ones mentioned, which create files without a specific mode.

- [pip_module.html#options](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html#options)
- [Unable to Set Umask / Mode for Git Module #10279 - Closed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10279)

I don't see a big disadvantage if you add this more explicit option where appropriate.  Maybe just a small annoyance when reading the role.

I note the `copy` module does not implement `umask`.  You can specify `mode`, it's just that this has slightly different semantics.  If you could specify `umask`, and the file already existed (regardless of content), then its mode would not be changed.  (In the role I'm working on, I think it's useful that the copy module made me think about this).

I note that the original message mentions pip breaking permissions on the ansible install under `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`.  Surely this would also be an issue with running `pip` manually.  It sounds like a defect in pip... but unlike OS packages, pip packages can also be installed inside a `virtualenv`, so it is much more complex for `pip` to determine the user's intention.  Arguably it is more of an example of a potentially unanticipated issue from using a restrictive umask.

Comment: In Ansible 2.2 the `command` module doesn't appear to have a `umask` option; you can change `command: foo` into `shell: umask 022 ; foo` as a work-around.